# How can you remove the option to use WinMerge when diffing with tortoise svn

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, winmerge

I just installed WinMerge on my windows machine. When doing setup it asked if I would like to use WinMerge in conjunction with tortoise svn. The link here sort of describes that functionality.

http://manual.winmerge.org/VersionControl.html

I really don't like this as I cannot do a normal tortoise svn diff....

Any idea how to remove this option? I cannot find anything in the options menu or any other menu

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look in the tortoise options. There is an option to choose which diff tool you use.

Answer (score 3):

[image: TortoiseSVN Settings - Diff Viewer]

TortoiseSVN Settings -> Diff Viewer -> Select 'TortoiseMerge'